# KeyError: False when I enter conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting the `KeyError: False` when I run this line:

```
df['Eligible'] = df[('DeliveryOnTime' == "On-time") | ('DeliveryOnTime' == "Early")]
```

I've been trying to find a way to execute this condition using `np.where` and `.loc()` as well but neither work. Open to other ideas on how to apply the condition to the new column `Eligible` using data from `DeliveryOnTime`

I've tried these:

`np.where`

```
df['Eligible'] = np.where((df['DeliveryOnTime'] == "On-time") | (df['DeliveryOnTime'] == "Early"), 1, 1)
```

`.loc()`

```
df['Eligible'] = df.loc[(df['DeliveryOnTime'] == "On-time") & (df['DeliveryOnTime'] == "Early"), 'Total Orders'].sum()
```

**Sample Data:**

```
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
      'DeliveryOnTime': ["On-time", "Late", "Early", "On-time", "On-time", "Late", "Early", "Early", "On-time"],
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#For the sake of example data, the count of `DeliveryOnTime` will be the total number of orders. 
df['Total Orders'] = df['DeliveryOnTime'].count()
```

Comment: You have 9 values for `ID` and 8 for `DeliveryOnTime`. Please fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right syntax is:

```
df['Eligible'] = (df['DeliveryOnTime'] == "On-time") | (df['DeliveryOnTime'] == "Early")

# OR

df['Eligible'] = df['DeliveryOnTime'].isin(["On-time", "Early"])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID DeliveryOnTime  Total Orders  Eligible
0   1        On-time             9      True
1   1           Late             9     False
2   1          Early             9      True
3   2        On-time             9      True
4   2        On-time             9      True
5   3           Late             9     False
6   4          Early             9      True
7   5          Early             9      True
8   5        On-time             9      True
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I'm able to run both fine but the issue is that when I do this, the number returned in `Eligible` is exactly the same as the `Total Orders`. This shouldn't be the case as there are rows that contain `Late`.

Comment: What do you mean? Do not use `.count` on `Eligible` column but `sum` IIUC

Comment: I'd like `Eligible` to be a number per ID. For example, ID 1 would have 1 order out of 2  `Eligible` and ID 5 would have 2 out of 2. Right now the values from `Total Order` and `Eligible` are exactly the same when this shouldn't be the case due to `Lates`

Comment: Woooooow. I've been doing this for hours and I swear I had already tried using `sum` for `Eligible` rather than `Count`. That solved it -_- Thank you Corralien

Comment: Hey sorry to ask but do you think you can help me with another question? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70116807/division-in-pandas-is-not-working-it-splits-the-value-after-a-condition-is-pas)

Answer (score 1):

The `df` references are misplaced.
Please try:

```
df['Elegible'] = (df['DeliveryOnTime'] == "On-time") | (df['DeliveryOnTime'] =="Early")
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID DeliveryOnTime  Elegible
0   1        On-time      True
1   1           Late     False
2   1          Early      True
3   2        On-time      True
4   2        On-time      True
5   3           Late     False
6   4          Early      True
7   5          Early      True
8   5          Early      True
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call these columns directly. Have a look at the solution that detects all rows that are either 'On-time' or 'Early'

```
df["eligible"] = df.DeliveryOnTime.isin(['On-time', 'Early'])
df['eligible'].groupby(df['ID']).transform('sum')
df
    ID  DeliveryOnTime  eligible    TotalOrders
0   1   On-time         True        2
1   1   Late            False       2
2   1   Early           True        2
3   2   On-time         True        2
4   2   On-time         True        2
5   3   Late            False       0
6   4   Early           True        1
7   5   Early           True        1
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I get the error `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 38, placement implies 1`

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. edited it

Comment: final edit. should work now